# Printing value of private variables of a class in a loop using member functions

Tags: c++, class, for-loop, class-variables

I'm building my first program in C++ and I'm stuck where I'm trying to print the value of *fee* multiple times using for loop after giving value once. By running the loop it is giving garbage value every time after giving right value at first time. I'm new to the class topic in C++. Please tell me how can I print the same value of private variable *fee* every time the loop runs.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class FEE
{
    private:
    int fee;
    public:
    void setfee()
    {
        cout<<"Enter the monthly fee= ";
        cin>>fee;
    }
    void showfee()
    {
        cout<<"Monthly fee is "<<fee<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    FEE stu[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
        stu[i].setfee();
        stu[i].showfee();
    }
}
```

Comment: You only call `setFee` on the first element of the `stu` array. Then you print all the (uninitialized) `fee` values of the remaining four elements.

Comment: In your `stu[]` array you are setting `fee` only in the first element

Comment: ok do i have to make fee an array here?

Comment: Why do you have the condition `if(i==0)`? Why do you call `setfee` only once and only on the `stu[0]` object?

Comment: because I want to set the same fee amount for every student and then autoprint it in a file for every stu[] array variable.

Comment: @SagarMavai Just remove the `if(i==0)` condition which is unnecessary here.

Comment: That's not how member variables work. A (non-static) member variable is a member of the *object*, not the class. Perhaps you should reconsider the `setfee` function, to instead of asking the user for input, get the input as an argument? Then you can get the input for the fee once in the `main` function, and use one loop to call `setfee`. Then you can do a second loop where you call `showfee`.

Comment: And if this is really the very first C++ program you have written, then you have skipped quite a lot of the early chapters of your beginners book. I recommend you invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) and read them from the very beginning, not skipping anything. That should help you understand variables and objects better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem** is that you're calling the `setfee` member function only for the first object in the array `stu`. And since the array `stu` was **default initialized** meaning its elements were also default initialized, the data member `fee` of each of those elements inside `stu` has an **indeterminate value**. So, calling `showfee` on the elements on which `setfee` was not called, is **undefined behavior** since for those elements `fee` has indeterminate value and you're printing the value inside `showfee`.

> because I want to set the same fee amount for every student and then autoprint it in a file for every stu[] array variable.

To solve this and do what you said in the above quoted statement, you can ask the user for the fee inside the `main` and then pass the input as an argument to the `setfee` member function. For this we have to change `setfee` member function in such a way that it has an `int` parameter. Next, using a 2nd for loop we could print the `fee` of each of the elements inside `stu` using `showfee` member function. This is shown [below](https://onlinegdb.com/MiVNOz_wB):

```
#include<iostream>

class FEE
{
    private:
    int fee = 0; //use in-class initializer for built in type
    public:
    void setfee(int pfee)
    {
        fee = pfee;
        
    }
    void showfee()
    {
        std::cout<<"Monthly fee is "<<fee<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    FEE stu[5];   //default initiailized array 
    
    int inputFee = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"Enter the monthly fee= ";
        std::cin>>inputFee;
        
        //call setfee passing the inputFee
        stu[i].setfee(inputFee);
        
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        stu[i].showfee();
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/MiVNOz_wB)

Also, note that using a `std::vector` instead of built in array is also an option here.

Some of the changes that i made include:

1. Added a parameter to the `setfee` member function.
2. Used **in-class initializer** for the `fee` data member.
3. The input fee is taken inside `main` which is then passed to the `setfee` member function for each of the element inside `stu`.
4. The member function `showfee` is called for each of the element inside `stu` using the 2nd for loop.